# Objective-C UITableView weird transparent effect when didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a weird behavior, when i select an entry of my tableview, during the transition to the detailsview i see my tableview like a ghost and i dont know why .... look at the picture.

[image]

maybe the problem is coming because the image of the food is a little bit transparent, i use the following code to do the transparancy effect :

in viewDidLoad method

```
_backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

i want to keep the same result but with this weird effect.

i tried to fix it in putting this line in the viewDidappear, but it doesnt cool, because user see the picture with full alpha and just after the food picture is displayed with transparency.

i hope than somebody have an idea.

Comment: Put a black view behind the image view.

Comment: Yeah i just set the background Color to black of the view who contain the imageview, and it works good.

the contentview was clearColor.... i'm sorry, i'm forgetful man.

thanks a lot !

Comment: @Barzull please add the solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: is it right like that ?

Comment: remove the tableView cell selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

my issues was solved by simply set the contentview of my imageview from clear to black. thanks to rmaddy

_poiDetailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];